# Disable lazy loading in peewee

Tags: python, python-2.7, peewee

We are investigating whether we should move from SQLalchemy to peewee for our project. We would like to disable lazy loading of properties so that they are only loaded if they were explicitly joined in the executed query. For example:

```
    for topping in Topping.select().where(Topping.stock > 0):
        print " - %s (%s): %s pieces left" % (topping.name, topping.category.name, topping.stock)
```

prints :

- Mozzarella (Cheese): 50 pieces left
- Basil (Herb): 100 pieces left
- Pepperoni (Meat): 60 pieces left

In my query I did not explicitly join with ToppingCategory yet it seems to fetch its name. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

It's costing you a query-per-row to lookup the category. Check out the docs on N+1 query problems: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#nplusone

When you access the FK (category), if it's not available peewee will load it, which requires a SELECT statement.

In your example you'll need to either:

a) eagerly load the category
b) do not access the category

For a), you would write:

```
 query = Topping.select(Topping, ToppingCategory.name).where(Topping.stock > 0)
 for topping in query:
     print topping.name, topping.category.name
```

Comment: Clear @coleifer . my question is if there is a way for raising an error when a developer tries to access the category without having it fetched. Also is there a way to get the category id without having to load the whole object? thanks

Comment: Yes, the category id will be selected by default. YOu can access it using "topping.category_id" without incurring a query. You can see how "assertQueryCount" is implemented in the tests if you're curious about raising exceptions. Basically attaches a query log handler and looks at counts of log messages. YOu could also monkeypatch execute_sql().